# How to archive (zip) File with apache commons

Tags: java, apache-commons-compress

How can I archive two files in java?

I thought of code like:

```
public void archiveFiles(FileInputStream file1, FileInputStream file2, String fileName) throws IOException, ArchiveException {
  ZipArchiveOutputStream zipArchiveOutputStream = new ZipArchiveOutputStream(new File(fileName));
  ZipArchiveEntry zipArchiveEntry = new ZipArchiveEntry("");
  zipArchiveEntry.setSize(subpoenaFile.getChannel().size());
  zipArchiveOutputStream.putArchiveEntry(zipArchiveEntry);
```

But I am stuck; can someone help me completing this?

Comment: I improved the formatting of code; and tried to express the underlying issue. But the question is still a bit unclear - missing a clear explanation on what is expected from the readers how to help.

Comment: by using `putArchiveEntry` twice???